# Мне нужно изменить все размеры текста на html страницы при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Что-то типа адаптива для слабовидящих, только просто увеличение и уменьшение font-size на 3 пункта.
Как мне обратиться к font-size всего текста на сайте?

Comment: Можно просто менять размер шрифта в тегах  `<html>` или `<body>`. В остальных местах везде использовать размеры шрифта в `em` или `rem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте рекурсивно

```js
function resize (element, size) {
  const s = `;font-size: ${size}px`;
  element.setAttribute("style", element.getAttribute("style") + s);
  for (let i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
    resize(element.children[i], size);
  }
}
resize(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], 10); // 10 размер шрифта в пикселях
```